# Architecture based OpenSSL package to be removed

Tags: linux, openssl, rpm

I am trying to build an rpm using the source code of an open source tool. while doing it , I see below error :

```
gcc -O9 -march=x86-64 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv dbutils.o config.o repmgrd.o log.o strutil.o -L/opt/app/Ionix/smarts-ncm/db/controldb/lib -lpgport -L/opt/app/Ionix/smarts-ncm/db/controldb/lib -lpq -L/opt/app/Ionix/smarts-ncm/db/controldb/lib  -Wl,-rpath,'/opt/app/Ionix/smarts-ncm/db/controldb/lib',--enable-new-dtags  -lpgport -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lreadline -ltermcap -lcrypt -ldl -lm  -o repmgrd
/usr/bin/ld: **cannot find -lssl**
```

Upon doing some research , I understood that it's because there are multiple openssl packages ( different architecture ) installed on my machine :

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME}\t%{ARCH}\n' | grep openssl
openssl097a     i386
openssl x86_64
openssl i686
```

The question is , which openssl package can I remove from here and how ? There will be many dependencies for this that might affect other packages as well. How can I ignore to not uninstall/remove the dependencies. Moreover , I tried to uninstall all the packages of openssl on another server and ran into a bigger problem. Now I cant even access that system so I want to be 100% sure this time. Is there a way to find out which one of the above is in active / enabled state ?

Here's the details of the machine I am working on :

```
2.6.18-371.el5 #1 SMP Mon Sep 30 16:34:30 PDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks ,
Bhavin

Comment: Multiple versions of the package wouldn't cause it not to be found. That doesn't make sense. What is more likely is that you don't have the `-devel` version of the packages installed. You should install the appropriate `openssl-devel` package for your system (and unless you really need it probably remove the `openssl097a` package).

Comment: Thank you Etan , That indeed worked. Good that I posted the detailed question and not just the symptom of the problem ! Thank you once again !